# Split long CSV string into multiple string variables

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a long CSV string that can have a maximum length of 44,119 characters. I have a SQL stored procedure that accepts 1 to 6 parameters, each of `varchar(8000)` that way dividing the long CSV into multiple parameters and passing it to the stored procedure.

My stored procedure works fine, but how can I divide a long CSV into different string variables such that they don't exceed string length of 8000 characters?

For example:

```
string myLongCSV = "1,2,345,5674,234,22,34..." //a long CSV
```

I cannot use `SubString (0, 8000)` as the 8,000th character might be breaking a number in the long CSV and not a comma.

I want to write the code in C# to make it divide all the numbers in the long CSV into different string variables making each variable length not exceeding 8000 characters.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, might TVPs be a better choice? Passing CSV into SQL is generally not a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, modify your SQL stored procedure to use a single parameter of data type `VACHAR(MAX)`, because that stores a maximum of 2,147,483,647 characters.

If you cannot, use `String.Split` function, like this:

```
string[] words = myLongCSV.Split(',');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    // some logic here to construct your parameters and check their length.
}
```

Comment: I was using sql stored proc with varchar(max) but when executing it with a long parameter, it used to cut off after 8000 characters.

Comment: How are you calling the SP from your SP? ADO.NET? Entity Framework? You may be using the wrong argument data type in your code.

Comment: I just tested it using the query editor from SQL Server management studio like Exec MyStoredProc '1,2,3,...' //long csv file. But ultimately I want to call it from my C# code.

Comment: Make sure to use VARCHAR(MAX) data type. Also check your SSMS options. If you are doing a SELECT, there is a default cut-off length in the returned results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The idea is to get the 8,000th character, if it's a number, then decrease index until it's ',' and at that point you can do `Substring()`, like this:

```
string s = "123,45636...";      
int index = 7;

while (true)
{
    if (s[index] == ',')
    {
        s = s.Substring(0, index);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        index--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but you probibly want to implment this using [`index = String.LastIndexOf(',', 8000)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3.aspx) so you don't need to loop.

Comment: Finally I created a varchar(Max) field in database and passing the entire 44119 characters as a CSV string. When I used to use Split in stored proc to separate the CSV by comma, it was chopping off the data after 8000 characters but using charindex and getting the data one by one worked for me.